# Search field not working in remote (experitest) chorme v91

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, search

I have a search field which is working in chrome in desktop version when i try to execute the same script in remote experitest its not working [search filed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxQ8i.png)

1)i am passing the data from the json and its working fine in the desktop version and in remore lower version of chrome.
2)When i try to execute it in remote from chrome version 91 its taking the near by store not the data from json.
3)i tried with wait command but still its not working

```
if (Region().contains("IN")) {
        setText(this.gbnlPostcodeinputfield, Location);
        gbnlsearchButton.waitUntilClickable().click();
        clickElement(this.gbBookbutton);
```

when i tried to execute once the search page is launched set Text is not working directly its searching the nearest location. Its happening only in version 91 in chrome

Comment: 1. Print the element before performing action and see. 2. Have you debugged?

Answer (score 0):

The issueis with experitest .I have disabled geo location in framework which is not working for chrome version 91.due to this its taking the near by store and script is getting failed